# How do I have date and time form submitted in SQL database?

Tags: sql

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Email, Telephone, PensionPot, BestTime)
VALUES
   ('$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Telephone]','$_POST[PensionPot]','$_POST[BestTime]'    )";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

    ?>
```

The code above is a form which submits to an sql database however in the database I want to be able to see the date and time the form was submitted? How would I do this?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, your question is not very clear, please try to rephrase it and include a problem statement,

Comment: Yeah, explain better your task

Comment: Thanks, I edited it for you hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Ok, now that's clear. Follow @Quandary advice ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Email, Telephone, PensionPot, BestTime, your_datetimefieldname)
VALUES ('$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Telephone]','$_POST[PensionPot]','$_POST[BestTime]', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the field is called submissiondate, your line would be :

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Email, Telephone, PensionPot, BestTime,submissiondate)
VALUES ('$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Telephone]','$_POST[PensionPot]','$_POST[BestTime]',CURDATE()    )";
```

EDIT : Sorry I missed the "time" part of your question. you can then use :

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Email, Telephone, PensionPot, BestTime,submissiondate)
    VALUES ('$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Telephone]','$_POST[PensionPot]','$_POST[BestTime]',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()    )";
```

Please note it's very unsecure to perform database queries as you do without sanitazing input. You should use prepared statements !

Comment: Thanks Bartdude for your reply to my question. I am afraid I am a complete novice in SQL so unsure how to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can simply set the default value of the column in the database to be the current timestamp. This way you don't have to worry in your code to always insert the current timestamp.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD COLUMN created timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP /*and optionally:*/ ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```